# Proving $(a^2 + 1)(b ^2 + 1)(c ^2 + 1) ≥ 2(ab + bc + ca)$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers.

Tags: inequality

The inequality above seems very compelling for the pqr-method.
So this was my attempt-
$$ LHS = (a^2 + 1)(b^2 + 1)(c^2 + 1) = 1 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 + a^2b^2c^2 $$
Now substituting $p = a+b+c$ , $q = ab+bc+ca$ and $r = abc$.
$$ LHS = 1 + p^2 - 2q + q^2 - 2pr + r^2 \geq 2q \Rightarrow 1 + p^2 + q^2 + r^2 \geq 4q + 2pr $$
It's quite well-known that $p^2\geq 3q$ and $q^2\geq 3pr$. So,
$$ 1 + 3q + 3pr + r^2 \geq 4q + 2pr \Rightarrow 1 + pr + r^2 \geq q $$
But I don't know how to prove it. It can also be seen that $a\ge b\ge c$, but I can't exploit symmetry.
Any help is thankfully welcome.

Comment: since there is no equality condition for $a = b = c,$ using inequalities that requires this condition will not be useful for you. In other words, $p^2 = 3q$ if and only if $a = b= c.$ I would just write the whole thing as a quadratic in $a$ find it's minimum in terms of $b$ and $c$, then show that minimum is non-negative.

Comment: @dezdichado Yes, I destroyed the equality case. Wouldn't you just write it in a quadratic of $a$ and show the discriminant is negative? Well, there is a sixth degree expression in the$ LHS$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write LHS - RHS as a quadratic in $a$, then the discriminant is:
$$D = 4(b+c)^2 - 4((b^2+1)(c^2+1)-2bc)(b^2+1)(c^2+1).$$
But $(b^2+1)(1+c^2)\geq (b+c)^2$ by C-S and $(b^2+1)(c^2+1)-2bc = b^2c^2+(b-c)^2+1\geq 1,$
so the discriminant is non-positive.

Comment: Would it be useful to see the equality case?

Comment: there is an equality case only when the quadratic has a real root. However, you can do more with the discriminant: the second inequality used above is equality only when $b = c = 0$, while the first C-S attains equality only when $b = c = 1.$ So the discriminant is actually always negative.

Comment: I think the equality case actually exists. I checked my question twice, and it is correct. There you see $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\geq2(ab+bc+ca)$. The sign is not a strict inequality, but **greater than or equal to**. This says that equality condition holds at some $a,b,c$. So where does it hold?

Comment: I literally proved to you in the previous comment that that was impossible. Choosing to ignore a completely valid proof is not gonna help you get better at mathematics. Besides, $\geq$ includes the possibility of $>$, so you cannot logically deduct the equality must be attained. I can write $6\geq 5$ and it will be completely fine.

Answer (score 3):

*Proceeding along your approach*:

It suffices to prove that $1 + p^2 - 2q + q^2 - 2pr + r^2 \ge 2q$.

Since $p^2 \ge 3q, q^2 \ge 3pr$, it suffices to prove that
$1 + 3q - 2q + q^2 - \frac{2}{3}q^2 \ge 2q$
or $1 - q + \frac{q^2}{3} \ge 0$
or $\frac{1}{3}(q - \frac{3}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{4} \ge 0$ which is true. We are done.

Comment: How did you get the second inequality? Please explain little more.

Comment: @BookOfFlames Do you mean $p^2 - 3q = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca \ge 0$?

Comment: I meant how did you reach $1 + 3q - 2q + q^2 - \frac{2}{3}q^2 \ge 2q$ from $1 + p^2 - 2q + q^2 - 2pr + r^2 \ge 2q$  ?

Comment: @BookOfFlames Since $p^2 \ge 3q$, $-2pr \ge -\frac{2}{3}q^2$ and $r^2 \ge 0$, we have $1 + p^2 - 2q + q^2 - 2pr + r^2 \ge 1 + 3q - 2q + q^2 - \frac{2}{3}q^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $2(ab + bc + ca) \leqslant 2(|a||b| + |b||c| + |c||a|)$ and
$$(a^2 + 1)(b ^2 + 1)(c ^2 + 1) = (|a|^2 + 1)(|b| ^2 + 1)(|c| ^2 + 1),$$
so we need to prove the inequality when $ a,\,b,\,c \geqslant 0.$

Indeed, easy to check $3t^2 \geqslant 3t-1.$ Now, using the AM-GM we have
$$(a^2 + 1)(b ^2 + 1)(c ^2 + 1) \geqslant a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 1 + a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2$$
$$ \geqslant a^2+b^2+c^2+1+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^4}$$
$$ \geqslant a^2+b^2+c^2+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}.$$
Therefore we will show that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2} \geqslant 2(ab+bc+ca).$$
Which is very known ([here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h67050p395483), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601427/prove-that-a2b2c23-sqrt3a2b2c2-geq-2abbcca)).

Comment: How did $1+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^4}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$ by AM-GM?

Comment: It's easy $3t^2 \geqslant 3t - 1,$ with $t = \sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag For those of us not so experienced with inequalities, it would be instructive of you to supply a proof for the final inequality (the one you say is well-known).

Comment: the last inequality is called Popovicu's inequality and while it's certainly well-known in contest math community, it is not as elementary as, say, Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ But it's indeed, well known. For the proof use Schur and Muirhead.

Comment: @dezdichado Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you as well for the reference.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thank you, I was updated the proof. Moreover it's called Shleifer's inequality.